# Simple Elasticsearch PDF Text Search using german language

Tags: elasticsearch, pdf, ocr, apache-tika

I can handle/extract the text from my PDF-Files, I don't know quite know if I am going the right way about how to store my content in Elasticsearch.

My PDF-Texts are mostly German - with letters like "ö", "ä", etc.

In order to store EVERY character of the content, I "escape" necessary characters and encode them properly to JSON so I can store them.

For example:

I want to store the following (PDF) text:

```
Öffentliche Verkehrsmittel. TestPath: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```

I convert and upload it to Elasticsearch like this:

```
{"text":"\\u00D6ffentliche Verkehrsmittel. TestPath: C:\\\\Windows\\\\explorer.exe"}
```

**My question is: Is this the right way to store documents like this?**

Comment: What analyzer are you using for the german text?

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm sorry. I have not set up an analyzer. Do I need to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch comes up with a wide range of [inbuilt language-specific analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) and if you are creating the text field and storing your data, by default standard analyzer is used. which you change like below:

```
{

    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title.german" :{
                "type" :"text",
                "analyzer" : "german"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also check the tokens generated by language analyzer in your case german using [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)

```
{
    "text" : "Öffentliche",
    "analyzer" : "german"
}
```

**And generated token**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "offentlich",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Tokens for `Ö`

```
{
    "text" : "Ö",
    "analyzer" : "german"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "o",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 1,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:- it converted it to plain text, so now whether you search for `Ö` or `ö` it will come in the search result, as the same analyzer is applied at query time if you use the match query.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you also please provide an example (wildcard) search query, that let's me search for example: *ffent* oder Öf* (I would like to be able to search within the entire text and get the results). Thank you in advance

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, Sure but you are asking two different unrelated questions in the same question and even your current question is quite big and contains too much info, I would suggest you ask a another question for wildcard search and give some sample document and expected documents, and comment me the question link and I shall post the answer if you do in next 20 mins :)

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, I also edited you question to make it more precise and to the point :), please be quick and would like to resolve another query before I go to bed :)